# Breeze.js audit log

Tags: breeze

We are using breeze.js on client side for data access layer over entity framework.

We need to maintain the audit log for all the data changes on server.

Can somebody please advise what could be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two options that occur to me are either

1) Server side triggers

2) Use the Breeze *beforeSaveEntities* mechanism to intercept the Breeze *saveChanges* call and add audit records directly in code on the server.

Comment: Well we have been forced not use to Triggers for some reason. We need to have code at controller level that would populate the audit log before saving an entity to the database.

Comment: beforeSaveEntities sounds like a good plan though. Just wanted to check is there any better way than this.

Comment: This one of the primary use cases for beforeSaveEntities.  It's actually not that hard to use. Of course, I'm biased. :)

Comment: I did the required job using BeforeSaveEntity using entityInfo.OriginalValuesMap which gives me list of original values and this dictionary only holds properties which has been modified. So ultimately it servers two purpose to me. It gives me list of all properties modified withing entity and it's original value as well.