# Determine which entity properties have been modified in BeforeEntitySave

Tags: breeze

Using a custom EFContextProvider, I want to check which properties have been modified on an entity before it saves, so that I can implement:

- Security: The client has permission to change only certain properties of an entity.
- Auditing: Whenever certain properties are changed, the change needs to be logged.

There are suggestions on SO to use OriginalValuesMap to determine the modified properties, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17471823/securing-breeze-on-the-server-to-prevent-malicious-updates-to-foreign-keys) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580440/breeze-js-audit-log). If the original value differs from the new value, the property has been modified. However, these original values are supplied by the client, and thus can be forged to match the new values, bypassing this check.

The first SO question I linked suggests this is not an issue, because if the original values are forged in such a way, those properties won't be saved anyway:

> For any other "unchanged" property, which we are not using in any way, we don't need to worry if it has been tampered with because, even if it has, the tampered value will not be persisted to the database

This is untrue however, as long as *all* modified properties on the entity have their original values forged. For example, the following code will bypass server-side security checks based on OriginalValuesMap and still save to the database:

```
manager.fetchEntityByKey('Employee', 42).then(function (result) {
    var employee = result.entity;
    employee.Salary(1000000); // do you think HR will notice?
    delete employee.entityAspect.originalValues.Salary;
    return manager.saveChanges();
});
```

When Breeze .NET receives the entity, it adds the entity to an Entity Framework context in Modified state, and with no properties marked as modified, Entity Framework's behaviour is to save *all* the supplied property values to the database.

IMO this is a security bug in EFContextProvider.HandleModified, where it overrides the EF entity state to Modified (there is even a comment in that method warning not to do so). In any case, what is the correct way to determine which properties have changed and are about to be saved?

Answer (score 0):

In your Context intercept Save and check if it is legal save or not. For the sake of explanation, let's say you want to save entity of type RestrictedClass and you defined table RestrictedClasses which imitates table in your database.

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (
            var entry in
                this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                    .Where((e => (e.State == (EntityState) Breeze.WebApi.EntityState.Modified))))
        {
            if (entry.Entity.GetType() == typeof(RestrictedClass))
            {
                var entity = entry.Entity as RestrictedClass;
                var originalEntities = RestrictedClasses.Where(e => e.Id = entity.Id).toList();
                if (originalEntities.Count == 0) continue; // user is trying to add, illegal since it says it's modified, you do different check for EntityState.Added
                var originalEntity = originalEntities[0]; // there should be only one, unique ID
                //.... now you check differences between entity and originalEntity and decide whether it's legal or not based on user role.
```